# Why does my Grease Pencil object become 'transparent' depending on the angle?

Tags: grease-pencil

I am trying to determine why my grease pencil object will sometimes become 'transparent' depending on the angle I view it.
By 'transparent' I mean, other grease pencil objects that are behind it will suddenly be rendered or drawn in front of and overlap visually even though it is behind the grease pencil object in 3d space. Additionally, when the grease pencil object becomes 'transparent' it will show grid overlays that are behind it, when previously it would block it out.

[image: Example of grease pencil becoming 'transparent' depending on angle]

In the gif example, the leaves and base of the tree trunk will 'flicker behind' the moss ball at the base which is behind the leaves 3Dimensionally. The tree is a different grease pencil object from the moss ball base. The tree stroke layers are set to 3D location and the moss ball base stroke layers are set to 2D Layers. I have toggling each of these settings but neither had an effect on this issue. I have also attempted to toggle Z pass but that didn't do anything either. I have recreated each individual component of this project and the outcome is still the same, that some angle change what gets rendered on top.

What is causing the tree grease pencil object to become 'transparent' that it will allow the moss ball grease pencil object to be rendered above it depending on the angle it is viewed in the viewport?